# Why should I set the Application Name to Drive.Builder when using Google Drive on Android?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm getting this warning

```
Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
```

I know how to set the app name, but I need to know what is it for. Since it's just a warning, I believe I don't need it, but if it's there, there must be a reason and I may want to use it.

I can't find it anywhere.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
The error is thrown at this line:

```
gDrive = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
```

Comment: Could you add the code you are using? Especially the one used to create the instance of DriveService and at which line the error is thrown?